# Proxy works well except for one particular page

Tags: node.js, https, proxy

I'm testing [this](https://github.com/nimit95/Forward-Proxy/blob/master/server.js) basic HTTP/HTTPS proxy. It works ok except for this [page](https://medium.com/), the browser shows; **This site can't be reached**

```
const net = require("net");

const server = net.createServer();

server.on("connection", (clientToProxySocket) => {
  console.log("Client Connected To Proxy");
  clientToProxySocket.once("data", (data) => {

    let isTLSConnection = data.toString().indexOf("CONNECT") !== -1;
    let serverPort = 80;
    let serverAddress;
    if (isTLSConnection) {
      serverPort = data.toString().split("CONNECT ")[1].split(" ")[0].split(":")[1];
      serverAddress = data.toString().split("CONNECT ")[1].split(" ")[0].split(":")[0];
    } else {
      serverAddress = data.toString().split("Host: ")[1].split("\r\n")[0];
    }

    console.log(serverAddress);
    //Connection proxy to the server
    let proxyToServerSocket = net.createConnection(
      {
        host: serverAddress,
        port: serverPort,
      },
      () => {
        console.log("PROXY TO SERVER SET UP");
        /*if(serverAddress==="medium.com")//<----------------- breakpoint
          debugger;
        */
        if (isTLSConnection) {
          clientToProxySocket.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n");
        } else {
          proxyToServerSocket.write(data);
        }

        clientToProxySocket.pipe(proxyToServerSocket);
        proxyToServerSocket.pipe(clientToProxySocket);

        proxyToServerSocket.on("error", (err) => {
          console.log("PROXY TO SERVER ERROR");
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
    );
    clientToProxySocket.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("CLIENT TO PROXY ERROR");
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
});

server.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("SERVER ERROR");
  console.log(err);
  throw err;
});

server.on("close", () => {
  console.log("Client Disconnected");
});

server.listen(8124, () => {
  console.log("Server runnig at http://localhost:" + 8124);
});
```

I cannot debug it without getting into the node's core which is so complex to me. The console shows no errors neither, when the browser tries to load *medium.com*, the console prints it as if it were any other page, no error:

```
...
Client Connected To Proxy
medium.com
PROXY TO SERVER SET UP
Client Connected To Proxy
safebrowsing.googleapis.com
PROXY TO SERVER SET UP
Client Connected To Proxy
app.link
PROXY TO SERVER SET UP
...
```

Could there be anything wrong with this page?

Thanks in advance. *(My english isn't native)*